# Spring security works on localhost but not on server

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I've a Spring Boot based application.  I added the following section to integrate Spring Security in it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also added following lines to application.properties:

security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=xyzabcd

This works as expected when I hit:

http://`localhost`:8080

But when I deploy on our server & hit:  http://`servername`:8080

I first get a dialog box that says "Realm: Spring". When I enter *correct* username & password it doesn't take it and the dailog box says "Realm: Realm” & it still doesn’t accept username & password.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: How do you run your app locally and how do you run it "on server"?

Comment: Andrei - On both machines I am using following command:

nohup java -jar ./target/xyz-rest-service-0.1.0.jar &

Comment: Are you overriding the security properties in some other file?

Comment: OMG!!  I am soo freaking dumb!  I've my own application.properties file in my classpath.  On localhost, I added the 2 properties & on the server I thought I did, but hadn't!  'geoand' your question made me look & sure enough that fixed it!  Thanks a lot 'geoand' & 'Andrei'.